# Laravel 5.3, How is file name generated?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In laravel 5.3 when we save the uploaded file to storage like in  code below.

```
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $path = $image->store();
```

It gives us a path that includes a file name.
How is that file name generated?

It is some kind of hash but what exactly?
hash of server time during upload, hash of file contents or something else?
Which hashing algorithm does it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name is generated by hashing the contents of the file using md5 algorithm in laravel 5.3

I checked it by uploading a file to laravel 5.3 server and comparing the name it gives to a result given by an online md5 hash generator.
But I haven't checked for other version of laravel.

Answer (score 1):

While I was going through the documentation, in my days, I concluded it was UUID.

> .....path should not contain a file name, since a **unique ID will automatically** be generated to serve as the file name.

Refer to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files)

**What is UUID?**

It  is a 128-bit number used to identify information in computer systems. Read details: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already got my answer and it is not UUID as you suggested but md5 hash of contents of the file. I lost the link but i got it from some github thread about a chance of name collision. I even checked by uploading a file and the name it gives against an online md5 has generator. So at least for laravel 5.3 it is a md5 hash of contents of the file.